# What is best way to create a separate API (Bounded context) to store and retrieve files, including images?

Tags: c#, rest, api, domain-driven-design

I am developing a project in which there are lots of files to be stored. I have created a separate API for file stuff, sending information to that API is via `NServiceBus` messaging mechanism.

For example, to save an image of a product, in product management API, after validating image (inside entity), I resend some of its information like `Base64String`, fileName, a unique-id for file and also aggregate root-name (here is Product) to file service API. I just store image path in aggregate for example:

```
"/Product/C54AABD2-1D03-4C01-976D-6478D3963AF0.jpg"
```

and then pass the file as base64 to File Service API to be stored:

```
public void SetImage(string base64Image, string imageId,string extension)
{
    if (!IsBase64(base64Image))
    {
        throw new ImageBase64FormatException();
    }

    this.ImageId = imageId;
    this.ImagePath = $"/{nameof(Product)}/{imageId}.{extension}";

     AddDomainEvent(new ProductImageChangedEvent(this.Id.Id,this.ImageId,base64Image,$"{imageId}.png",nameof(Product)));
}
```

This is my scenario:

after the information reached in File Service API, in the File Service Solution, there is a console project named "BusDispathcer" which is supposed to be running like a windows service to handle raised events. In that always running Windows app, I would define a physical path where main File Service API would be located (`c:\wwwroot\...`) to store file in specified folder (entity name) and finally in UI (which is Angular) should add address of file service API (for example: `http://files.myDomain.com` and the main API would be in `productManagment.myDomain.com`) before every file path (for example: `/Product/C54AABD2-1D03-4C01-976D-6478D3963AF0.jpg`).

For example:

```
<img src="http://files.myDomain.com/Product/C54AABD2-1D03-4C01-976D-6478D3963AF0.jpg"/>
```

Is this approach correct/wrong or do you have any better suggestion to store files in different domain address?

Comment: Can you expand on what your concern is, or what you think is the design problem?

Comment: @SubhashBhushan, I want to host file service API in different location from main API, cause it's image might be used by different APIs.

Comment: By different APIs, do you mean different products/microservices/code-repositories? And will each have a separate service API endpoint (like `files.mydomain.dom`) to access their files?

Comment: @SubhashBhushan Yes they do. different micro-services

Comment: It's certainly not clear what you are asking. Would you be able to based on your comment above, it's not clear that there is a problem or question. If you need a reusable and generic way to store files because different parts of your system will require it then, yes, isolate that in a separate service.